# Область видимости в nuxt.js, как получить данные из стора в импортируемом файле?

Tags: nuxt.js

Есть файлы с подготовленными запросами, выглядит это так:
**base.js**

```
`use strict`;

import {requestToApi} from '../api.js'

export function locales() {
    return requestToApi('GET', '/locales');
}

export function translations() {
    return requestToApi('GET', '/translations');
}
```

В компонентах я могу обратиться примерно так:

```
let {status, data, errors} = await translations();
```

Функция **requestToApi** такая себе универсальная и удобная обертка (под капотом axios), которая разруливает все вопросы с запросами.
Все хорошо, только с каждым запросом, мне нужно кидать jwt-токен. А этот токен находится либо в куках либо в сторе.
Я бы хотел его получить внутри **requestToApi**, при этом не передавая его в каждом запроса.

Проблема такая, что ни в файле base.js, ни в ../api.js я не могу получить доступ ни к стору ни к кукам, вообще к компонентам nuxt.

Собственно вопрос, можно ли все-же как-то получить доступ находясь в импортированном файле, хоть к чему-нибуть (this пустой, window тоже)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Единственный рабочий вариант, который удалось найти, это записывать переменную глобально во Vue

```
Vue.prototype.$accessToken = '...value';
```